Why put capacitors to ground on a driver's outputs?
I'm currently experimenting with the VNQ7140AJ, a quad channel high-side driver with some diagnostic functions (datasheet).
The manufacturer also offers an evaluation board for this driver, which outlines it's schema on page 2 of it's datasheet.

As you can see, each output has a capacitor to ground. Why is that? The way I learned it, you generally want to avoid capacitance on switched signal lines, as it prolongs the rising and falling edges of the signal, thus distorting the characteristics of the input signal and limiting the effective switching speed.
Truth be told, the switching parameters on page 9 of the VNQ7140AJ's datasheet are quite large, making it unattractive for high speed signals anyway. Still, I don't understand why willingly add capacitance there.

Maybe ESD protection for the outputs?

The chip is intended to drive automotive loads in automotive environments, mainly lamps but also other resistive, inductive and capacitive loads.
In such applications there are simple wires going around in a bunch with other wires. Wires have inductance and two wires running next to each other has capacitance between them.
In most applications you only want as much bandwidth you need, and any switching speed that is unnecessarily fast is not needed and may cause signal reflections that bounce around in the wires. The capacitors may be used to limit the voltage slew rate in wires so there is not much capacitive crosstalk between them, and it also guarantees there is no signal reflections, overshoots and ringing if they are slow enough.
It also improves EMI, the slow signals on wires do not emit much electomagnetic interference and are also not so susceptible to electromagnetic interference being injected to them.
Fast changing currents, such as a lamp making a scratcy contact in the socket under vibration will have large current spikes. In the wire inductance, the fast currents can induce fast and large voltage spikes. The capacitor will limit these voltage spikes by absorbing the energy.
And like already mentioned elsewhere, it acts as a simple ESD protection.
